# Is it possible to put switch case inside while loop?

Tags: php, database, fpdf

The scenario is I am going to pull some data from the database and output it through pdf. I use `FPDF` to make it happen and I am on the part where I need to getthe **height** from the database and display it according to color.

*For example:*

- *If the height is **2-3Meters** then it should be color **brown***
- *If the height is **1-2Meters** then it should be color **yellow***
- *If the height is **<1Meter** then it should be color **blue***

[image]

**MY PROBLEM IS** I'm trying to insert `switch case` inside a `while loop` to put the **height** on the table where some other data are being displayed. The picture below shows where I want to implement the **colored cells**. It should be implemented at the "SS Height" column.

[image]

But it doesn't work and gave me this error.

[image]

This is my codes.

```
<?php

require('connection.php');

$sql="SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ssh REGEXP '^[^A-Za-z0-9]' ASC, ssh DESC";

$records=mysql_query($sql);
$fetch = mysql_fetch_array($records);

require("library/fpdf.php");

$pdf = new PDF('p', 'mm', 'Legal');
$title = 'Storm Surge Warning';
$pdf->SetTitle($title);
$pdf->AliasNbPages('{pages}');
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true,25);

$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetBorders(array('LT', 'LT', 'LT', 'LT', 'TLR'));
$pdf->SetWidths(array(30, 27, 35, 51, 51));
$pdf->SetAligns(array('C', 'C', 'C', 'L', 'L'));

$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 10);

$pdf->Row(array("SS Height",
            "Provinces",
            "Low Lying Coastal Areas in the Municipalities of:",
            "IMPACTS",
            "ADVICE/Actions to Take"), 1);

$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 11);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($records)){

$pdf->Row(array(
switch ($row['ssh']) { 
case '2-3Meters' : 
$pdf->SetFillColor(204, 153, 0); 
$pdf->Cell($row['ssh'], 1, 1, 'L', TRUE); 
break; 
case '1-2Meters' : 
$pdf->SetFillColor(255, 255, 0); 
$pdf->Cell($row['ssh'], 1, 1, 'L', TRUE); 
break; 
case '<1Meter' : 
$pdf->SetFillColor(51, 153, 255); 
$pdf->Cell($row['ssh'], 1, 1, 'L', TRUE); 
break; 

default: 
$pdf->Cell($row['ssh'], 1, 1, 'L', FALSE); 
break; 
}

    $row['provi'],
    $row['muni'],
    $row['impact'],
    $row['advice']), 1);
    }

$pdf->SetBorders(array('T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T'));
$pdf->Row(array('','','','',''), 1, false, 1);

$pdf->OutPut();
?>
```

Comment: why passing `TRUE` instead of value? try `switch ($row['ssh']) { 
case  '2-3Meters'  : `

Comment: And did you look at line 55? What was `$row['provi'],` supposed to do?

Comment: PD of [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them?](//stackoverflow.com/q/18050071)

Comment: @mario `$row['provi'],` is supposed to call the Provinces from the database.

Comment: But what is `$row['provi'],
    $row['muni'],
    $row['impact'],
    $row['advice']), 1);`? It looks like that's part of an array or function call, but the beginning is missing.

Comment: Is it supposed to be something like `$pdf->Row(array($row['provi'], $row['muni'], $row['impact'], $row['advice']), 1);`?

Comment: @Barmar the codes looks like this without the **_switch case_** `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($records)){

    $row['provi'],
    $row['muni'],
    $row['impact'],
    $row['advice']), 1);
    }`

Comment: That's not valid, you have mismatched parentheses.

Comment: Yup, sorry that was a typo. I fixed it and now it gives me the _Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'switch' (T_SWITCH), expecting ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\OJTTask\pdf.php on line 112_ error. I updated my codes below.

Comment: You can put a `switch` statement into a `while` statement. But you can't throw the `switch` into an `array(…)` expression. What is that supposed to do? There's no return value, all the case blocks just call functions.

Comment: It supposed to call data from the db and just display it. However on the _Height column_ each height should have cell color depending on it's value. @mario

Comment: It's fine now. I just have to adjust some designs to make it work perfectly. Your answer _"you can't throw the switch into an array(…) expression"_ fixed it. Thank you so much. @mario

Answer (score 1):

Your switch (TRUE) should use the field with the height
probably something like the code below:

```
switch ($row['ssh'] ) { 
case '2-3Meters' : {
   $pdf->SetFillColor(204, 153, 0); 
   $pdf->Cell($row['ssh'], 1, 1, 'L', TRUE); 
   break; 
}
case '1-2Meters' : {
    $pdf->SetFillColor(255, 255, 0); 
    $pdf->Cell($row['ssh'], 1, 1, 'L', TRUE); 
    break; 
}
case  '<1Meter' : {
    $pdf->SetFillColor(51, 153, 255); 
    $pdf->Cell($row['ssh'], 1, 1, 'L', TRUE); 
    break; 
}
default:
...
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. I updated my codes above as well. I got an error saying _Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'switch' (T_SWITCH), expecting ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\OJTTask\pdf.php on line 112 error._

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, without knowing how the FPDF API works, it seems it just retains global states.

So call, the switch + colorization first (an array map would be simpler), then add the ->Cell, and lastly the ->Row, as in:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($records)){

    switch ($row['ssh']) { 
        case '2-3Meters' : 
        $pdf->SetFillColor(204, 153, 0); 
        …
    }

    $pdf->Cell($row['ssh'], 1, 1, 'L', TRUE);

    $pdf->Row(array(1,2,3,4,1));
}
```